# Google wallet chooser call

Tags: java, android, android-pay

Chooser window with card editing was showing every time when MaskedWalletRequest was in process. But after the preauthorization was added (Client ID for Android application) the chooser window showed only once and then user couldnt chose card in the list of wallet cards cause the chooser isn`t shown.

Is there any way to call Google Wallet chooser popup window manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wallet.changeMaskedWallet` is the answer